# How to reorder my elements and/or float text around the image?

Tags: html, css, css-float, flexbox

I have been given the following markup that **cannot** change.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="some image"/>
    </div>
    <h3>Some Header the is in the wrong place</h3>
    <p class="blurbThing"></p>
    <div class="description">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean porttitor massa sed nisi eleifend, a molestie felis convallis. Curabitur luctus orci eget rhoncus eleifend. Vestibulum dui odio, feugiat non commodo vitae, luctus a nisl. Aliquam tempor nibh
            ac ante ullamcorper egestas. In ut risus quis elit ullamcorper sollicitudin in vel ante. Phasellus id magna sed erat elementum iaculis non sed dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur quis lectus mauris. Vivamus dictum libero nulla, vel egestas libero
            dictum ut. Maecenas aliquam lectus vitae arcu lacinia, sed aliquet erat porttitor. Maecenas maximus nunc vel nulla dictum finibus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec quam mi, condimentum at dolor sodales, facilisis mollis lacus. Nulla condimentum sagittis elit quis mollis. Vestibulum ultrices, risus eu sagittis tristique, purus augue egestas erat, eget auctor massa augue vitae mauris.
            Nulla at lacinia justo. Aenean nec arcu euismod, condimentum lectus vitae, rhoncus nisi. Fusce lorem tortor, tincidunt sed interdum eu, euismod ut purus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Donec ultrices eleifend pulvinar. Donec accumsan felis vel nunc porta pretium. Aenean tellus velit, ultrices quis viverra eget, vehicula vel odio. Ut nec iaculis dolor, eu aliquam felis. Proin quis maximus metus. Phasellus tincidunt tristique pulvinar.
            Nunc tincidunt aliquet tincidunt.
        </p>
        <p>
            Nullam ac consequat lorem. Praesent rhoncus consequat arcu ut tempus. Sed non mi fringilla, aliquet lectus in, sagittis dolor. Integer eu lacus consectetur, fringilla eros quis, blandit tellus. Quisque eu arcu dui. Integer finibus varius ultricies. Nulla
            vitae metus in velit suscipit cursus. Vestibulum ornare ac diam quis semper. Ut nunc massa, commodo ac lorem ut, faucibus tincidunt nulla. Proin sed urna eget diam ultricies consectetur ac eu tortor.
        </p>
        <p>
            Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc lobortis feugiat laoreet. Maecenas ligula nulla, ornare hendrerit tempus id, venenatis vitae lacus. Cras cursus a nulla ac dapibus. Class
            aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque et lacinia est. Sed quam orci, luctus eu eros et, congue bibendum ipsum. Nunc non sodales est.
        </p>
    </div>
    <hr class="clear">
</div>
```

So the goal is to get the html to render as per the following snippet:

```css
.container {
    max-width: 700px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;  
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.container > .image {
    max-width: 40%;
    min-width: 40%;
    min-height: 100px;
    float:right;
}

.container > .description {
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

.container > .description > * {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.container > .description > p {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.container > h3 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.container > hr {
    display: none;  
}

.container > .image > img{
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center center;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3>Some Header the is in the wrong place</h3>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="some image"/>
    </div>
    <p class="blurbThing"></p>
    <div class="description">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean porttitor massa sed nisi eleifend, a molestie felis convallis. Curabitur luctus orci eget rhoncus eleifend. Vestibulum dui odio, feugiat non commodo vitae, luctus a nisl. Aliquam tempor nibh
            ac ante ullamcorper egestas. In ut risus quis elit ullamcorper sollicitudin in vel ante. Phasellus id magna sed erat elementum iaculis non sed dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur quis lectus mauris. Vivamus dictum libero nulla, vel egestas libero
            dictum ut. Maecenas aliquam lectus vitae arcu lacinia, sed aliquet erat porttitor. Maecenas maximus nunc vel nulla dictum finibus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec quam mi, condimentum at dolor sodales, facilisis mollis lacus. Nulla condimentum sagittis elit quis mollis. Vestibulum ultrices, risus eu sagittis tristique, purus augue egestas erat, eget auctor massa augue vitae mauris.
            Nulla at lacinia justo. Aenean nec arcu euismod, condimentum lectus vitae, rhoncus nisi. Fusce lorem tortor, tincidunt sed interdum eu, euismod ut purus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Donec ultrices eleifend pulvinar. Donec accumsan felis vel nunc porta pretium. Aenean tellus velit, ultrices quis viverra eget, vehicula vel odio. Ut nec iaculis dolor, eu aliquam felis. Proin quis maximus metus. Phasellus tincidunt tristique pulvinar.
            Nunc tincidunt aliquet tincidunt.
        </p>
        <p>
            Nullam ac consequat lorem. Praesent rhoncus consequat arcu ut tempus. Sed non mi fringilla, aliquet lectus in, sagittis dolor. Integer eu lacus consectetur, fringilla eros quis, blandit tellus. Quisque eu arcu dui. Integer finibus varius ultricies. Nulla
            vitae metus in velit suscipit cursus. Vestibulum ornare ac diam quis semper. Ut nunc massa, commodo ac lorem ut, faucibus tincidunt nulla. Proin sed urna eget diam ultricies consectetur ac eu tortor.
        </p>
        <p>
            Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc lobortis feugiat laoreet. Maecenas ligula nulla, ornare hendrerit tempus id, venenatis vitae lacus. Cras cursus a nulla ac dapibus. Class
            aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque et lacinia est. Sed quam orci, luctus eu eros et, congue bibendum ipsum. Nunc non sodales est.
        </p>
    </div>
    <hr class="clear">
</div>
```

Note in the above snippet I have moved the `<h3>` tag to the top inside the container and everything is fine and dandy. However I cannot change this in my scenario.
I can use jQuery/JavaScript to do it, but I really don't want to, and would like to use CSS only.

I have tried using a flexbox approach to get it to re order but then I cannot get the text to wrap around the bottom of the image, e.g.

```css
.container {
    max-width: 700px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;  
    text-align: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.container > .image {
    max-width: 40%;
    min-width: 40%;
    min-height: 100px;
    order: 4;
}

.container > .specials-info {
    order: 2;
}

.container > .description {
    max-width: 60%;
    text-align: left;
    order: 3;
}

.container > .description > * {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.container > .description > p {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.container > h3 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    order: 1;
}

.container > hr {
    display: none;  
}

.container > .image > img{
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center center;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="some image"/>
    </div>
    <h3>Some Header the is in the wrong place</h3>
    <p class="blurbThing"></p>
    <div class="description">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean porttitor massa sed nisi eleifend, a molestie felis convallis. Curabitur luctus orci eget rhoncus eleifend. Vestibulum dui odio, feugiat non commodo vitae, luctus a nisl. Aliquam tempor nibh
            ac ante ullamcorper egestas. In ut risus quis elit ullamcorper sollicitudin in vel ante. Phasellus id magna sed erat elementum iaculis non sed dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur quis lectus mauris. Vivamus dictum libero nulla, vel egestas libero
            dictum ut. Maecenas aliquam lectus vitae arcu lacinia, sed aliquet erat porttitor. Maecenas maximus nunc vel nulla dictum finibus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec quam mi, condimentum at dolor sodales, facilisis mollis lacus. Nulla condimentum sagittis elit quis mollis. Vestibulum ultrices, risus eu sagittis tristique, purus augue egestas erat, eget auctor massa augue vitae mauris.
            Nulla at lacinia justo. Aenean nec arcu euismod, condimentum lectus vitae, rhoncus nisi. Fusce lorem tortor, tincidunt sed interdum eu, euismod ut purus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Donec ultrices eleifend pulvinar. Donec accumsan felis vel nunc porta pretium. Aenean tellus velit, ultrices quis viverra eget, vehicula vel odio. Ut nec iaculis dolor, eu aliquam felis. Proin quis maximus metus. Phasellus tincidunt tristique pulvinar.
            Nunc tincidunt aliquet tincidunt.
        </p>
        <p>
            Nullam ac consequat lorem. Praesent rhoncus consequat arcu ut tempus. Sed non mi fringilla, aliquet lectus in, sagittis dolor. Integer eu lacus consectetur, fringilla eros quis, blandit tellus. Quisque eu arcu dui. Integer finibus varius ultricies. Nulla
            vitae metus in velit suscipit cursus. Vestibulum ornare ac diam quis semper. Ut nunc massa, commodo ac lorem ut, faucibus tincidunt nulla. Proin sed urna eget diam ultricies consectetur ac eu tortor.
        </p>
        <p>
            Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc lobortis feugiat laoreet. Maecenas ligula nulla, ornare hendrerit tempus id, venenatis vitae lacus. Cras cursus a nulla ac dapibus. Class
            aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque et lacinia est. Sed quam orci, luctus eu eros et, congue bibendum ipsum. Nunc non sodales est.
        </p>
    </div>
    <hr class="clear">
</div>
```

In summary is there a way to achieve Snippet 1 with out altering the original HTML and without using JavaScript?

**Edit 1**

Just to clarify a bit in the image below on the left is Snippet 1. It is what I want to end up with (but the markup is different in that the `<h3>` tag is higher). On the right is Snippet 2, as close as I can get without editing the markup (which I cannot do) / using JavaScript (I can do but would rather use CSS only).

Note that I have used a flexbox to reorder the items, but at that point I cannot use a float on the image container.

[image]

**Edit 2**

A bit more clarification(apologies)

- The header(h3) must sit at the top and take 100% of the width. (no wrapping by just padding the image down).
- The Image will be 45% of the width but will change in height depending on diffent use cases.
- The Content of description will be x no of p tags with varying content.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what the difference is between the two. Maybe use placeholder images or show us screenshots of what you want vs what you have, instead?

Comment: @TylerH Notice that in first snippet the text is wrapped around the image. In second snippet it does not, it acts like image is in a completely different column.

Comment: @ManojKumar Yes, but to be clear, I want the *OP* to provide more detail so there is no confusion as to what he wants.

Comment: @ManojKumar you are correct. TylerH Ill mock up an image to explain it better i thought the code would be clearer then my terrible paint drawings :P

Comment: @TylerH Does the edit help clarify my question? I'm sorry if it confusing. I might refactor the whole question im just not sure if that is good practice.

Comment: i'm not sure what the issue is http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/mmtn1z2w/ your first css works with the html mark up

Comment: @RachelGallen The first example is of what he wants it to look like, but he can't change the markup to that.

Comment: @RachelGallen Note the position of the h3 tag :) sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this pretty easily with just using the `float` property on the `image` container and some `margin-top`. I won't go through line-by-line with what CSS properties I've changed, but here is a JSFiddle that doesn't change your HTML and achieves the layout you want. It has the added benefit of far fewer lines of CSS than using `flex`.

**Note:** Since I don't know what size your image actually is, I chose an explicit size based on your what your image looked like.

```css
.container {
    max-width: 700px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.container .image {
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.container > .image {
    float: right;
    width: 300px; /* just an example size */
    height: 150px; /* just an example size */
    background: grey; /* This is just to show you where the image would be */
}

.container > .description > * {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.container > .description > p {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.container > h3 {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="some image"/>
    </div>
    <h3>Some Header the is in the wrong place</h3>
    <p class="blurbThing"></p>
    <div class="description">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean porttitor massa sed nisi eleifend, a molestie felis convallis. Curabitur luctus orci eget rhoncus eleifend. Vestibulum dui odio, feugiat non commodo vitae, luctus a nisl. Aliquam tempor nibh
            ac ante ullamcorper egestas. In ut risus quis elit ullamcorper sollicitudin in vel ante. Phasellus id magna sed erat elementum iaculis non sed dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur quis lectus mauris. Vivamus dictum libero nulla, vel egestas libero
            dictum ut. Maecenas aliquam lectus vitae arcu lacinia, sed aliquet erat porttitor. Maecenas maximus nunc vel nulla dictum finibus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec quam mi, condimentum at dolor sodales, facilisis mollis lacus. Nulla condimentum sagittis elit quis mollis. Vestibulum ultrices, risus eu sagittis tristique, purus augue egestas erat, eget auctor massa augue vitae mauris.
            Nulla at lacinia justo. Aenean nec arcu euismod, condimentum lectus vitae, rhoncus nisi. Fusce lorem tortor, tincidunt sed interdum eu, euismod ut purus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Donec ultrices eleifend pulvinar. Donec accumsan felis vel nunc porta pretium. Aenean tellus velit, ultrices quis viverra eget, vehicula vel odio. Ut nec iaculis dolor, eu aliquam felis. Proin quis maximus metus. Phasellus tincidunt tristique pulvinar.
            Nunc tincidunt aliquet tincidunt.
        </p>
        <p>
            Nullam ac consequat lorem. Praesent rhoncus consequat arcu ut tempus. Sed non mi fringilla, aliquet lectus in, sagittis dolor. Integer eu lacus consectetur, fringilla eros quis, blandit tellus. Quisque eu arcu dui. Integer finibus varius ultricies. Nulla
            vitae metus in velit suscipit cursus. Vestibulum ornare ac diam quis semper. Ut nunc massa, commodo ac lorem ut, faucibus tincidunt nulla. Proin sed urna eget diam ultricies consectetur ac eu tortor.
        </p>
        <p>
            Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc lobortis feugiat laoreet. Maecenas ligula nulla, ornare hendrerit tempus id, venenatis vitae lacus. Cras cursus a nulla ac dapibus. Class
            aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque et lacinia est. Sed quam orci, luctus eu eros et, congue bibendum ipsum. Nunc non sodales est.
        </p>
    </div>
    <hr class="clear">
</div>
```

Comment: @TylerH the image needs to be inline with the p tags not the h3 tag. I cannot simply pad the image because then the h3 tag wraps for no apparent reason.

Comment: @ManojKumar My Snippet achieves the layout without using flexbox, which was not listed as a requirement.

Comment: @Spaceman Updated to be in line with the paragraphs. I also added `no-wrap` to the `h3` element so that it doesn't wrap.

Comment: @TylerH this works for me i think :) no-wrap ha so simple haha

Answer (score 1):

Used some CSS hacks to achieve the first layout in Flexbox.

1. Flexbox does not allow wrapping of text around the images, since it takes its own row or column.
2. Give the parent container `position: relative` and the child item image `position: absolute` and align with the `top` and `left` values.
3. You can adjust the width from the 2nd paragraph to last to occupy 100% width.

```css
.container {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width: 700px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}
.container > .image {
  max-width: 40%;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 40%;
  order: 4;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100px;
}
.container > .specials-info {
  order: 2;
}
.container > .description {
  order: 3;
  text-align: left;
}
.container > .description > * {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.container > .description > p {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.container > h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  order: 1;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.container > hr {
  display: none;
}
.container > .image > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}
.description > p:not(:first-child) {
  width: 100%;
}
.description > p:first-child {
  max-width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  </div>
  <h3>Some Header the is in the wrong place</h3>
  <p class="blurbThing"></p>
  <div class="description">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean porttitor massa sed nisi eleifend, a molestie felis convallis. Curabitur luctus orci eget rhoncus eleifend. Vestibulum dui odio, feugiat non commodo vitae, luctus a nisl. Aliquam tempor nibh
      ac ante ullamcorper egestas. In ut risus quis elit ullamcorper sollicitudin in vel ante. Phasellus id magna sed erat elementum iaculis non sed dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur quis lectus mauris. Vivamus dictum libero nulla, vel egestas libero
      dictum ut. Maecenas aliquam lectus vitae arcu lacinia, sed aliquet erat porttitor. Maecenas maximus nunc vel nulla dictum finibus.
    </p>
    <p>
      Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec quam mi, condimentum at dolor sodales, facilisis mollis lacus. Nulla condimentum sagittis elit quis mollis. Vestibulum ultrices, risus eu sagittis tristique, purus augue egestas erat, eget auctor massa augue vitae mauris.
      Nulla at lacinia justo. Aenean nec arcu euismod, condimentum lectus vitae, rhoncus nisi. Fusce lorem tortor, tincidunt sed interdum eu, euismod ut purus.
    </p>
    <p>
      Donec ultrices eleifend pulvinar. Donec accumsan felis vel nunc porta pretium. Aenean tellus velit, ultrices quis viverra eget, vehicula vel odio. Ut nec iaculis dolor, eu aliquam felis. Proin quis maximus metus. Phasellus tincidunt tristique pulvinar.
      Nunc tincidunt aliquet tincidunt.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nullam ac consequat lorem. Praesent rhoncus consequat arcu ut tempus. Sed non mi fringilla, aliquet lectus in, sagittis dolor. Integer eu lacus consectetur, fringilla eros quis, blandit tellus. Quisque eu arcu dui. Integer finibus varius ultricies. Nulla
      vitae metus in velit suscipit cursus. Vestibulum ornare ac diam quis semper. Ut nunc massa, commodo ac lorem ut, faucibus tincidunt nulla. Proin sed urna eget diam ultricies consectetur ac eu tortor.
    </p>
    <p>
      Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc lobortis feugiat laoreet. Maecenas ligula nulla, ornare hendrerit tempus id, venenatis vitae lacus. Cras cursus a nulla ac dapibus. Class
      aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque et lacinia est. Sed quam orci, luctus eu eros et, congue bibendum ipsum. Nunc non sodales est.
    </p>
  </div>
  <hr class="clear">
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like the ticket :o I will test it and get back.

Comment: This almost works however something which I haven't specified is that the markup is a template which is used x times on a page with different content for each. In some situations the content of each p tag in description may be shorter or longer and the image may be taller or shorter. In some of my test cases locally the code you provided makes the paragraph go under the image and disappear. What I could do to fix this is limit the image height but if possible I would like to not to that. Ill update the question with this information.

Comment: How about setting `min-height: 200px` to `p:first-child` although there will be some vertical space. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/b5mkaLjd/

Answer (score 0):

Use this `margin-top` for `.image` class in snippet1

```
.container > .image {
    max-width: 40%;
    min-width: 40%;
    min-height: 100px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:72px;
}
```

Comment: This will mean the h3 tag will wrap I wish to avoid this :)